# Displaying drop down menu for autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i used jquery ui autocomplete for genration autocompletions. Everything works fine, a dropdown menu appears, but the values are blanc. Howerer, when i scroll my mouse on those blank values, the input value changes with the suggested value.
This is a screenshot for what happens : http://hpics.li/b058523

this is my javascript code :

```
<!-- javascript pour AUTOCOMPLETION -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {


    $('#search').autocomplete({

            minLength: 2,
            source: '<%= posts_path(:json) %>', 
             focus: function(event, ui) {
                $('#search').val(ui.item.post.title);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#search').val(ui.item.post.title);
        $('#post_id').val(ui.item.post.id);
                return false;
            }
        })

_renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "ui-autocomplete", item ) 
                 .append( "<a>" + ui.item.post.title + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul ); 
        };

    });
    </script>


<!-- fin javascript pour autocompletion -->
```

it seems that .append(""+ui.item.post.title +"") doesn't add the value of the title between . (i checked that with chrome element inspector and no value written between  ).

What can be the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code here:

```
_renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "ui-autocomplete", item ) 
                 .append( "<a>" + ui.item.post.title + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul ); 
        };
```

The function is accepting `ul` but then you're calling `ui`. That could be the problem. Just a hunch.